# Collapse horizontal Bootstrap 3 navbar to a stacked one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

What I am trying to achieve with Bootstrap 3, is to have a horizontal (fixed) navigation bar on top, but collapse it on small screens to become something similar to "navigation drawers" on android (stacked, off canvas vertical navigation bar on the left which can be toggled).

Both can be achieved separately, but I need them to work this way.

I was thinking that maybe all I need is a way to be able to define classes for the navbar to only apply on small screens.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it so that when a screen is made smaller the `navbar` collapses into a list structure which can then be clicked and toggled. [This](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) page is an example of it and [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) page outlines all the options you have for `navbars`

This can be achieved by adding `"collapse"` attributes to the `classes`, `data-toggles` and `targets`.